# Subarray size in merge sort

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, mergesort

I am having trouble understanding the sizes of the subarrays in merge sort. In the following code:

```
   public void mergeSort(List<Integer> list, int low, int high){

       if(low<high){
           int mid = (high+low)/2;
           mergeSort(list,low, mid);
           mergeSort(list,mid+1,high);
           merge(list, low, mid, high);

       }
   }

   private void merge(List<Integer> list ,int low, int mid, int high){

       int lSize = mid-low+1;
       int rSize = high-mid;
   //etc 
   }
```

For the size of subarrays, I have to add a 1 to the left while the right array does not add a 1. I understand that if we had an array of size 10, the indexes would be 0..9 and lSize would be 4-0+1 and rSize is 9-4.

I'm not exactly sure how to word this, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around where to add the +1 without doing this whole example array of size 10 in my head. If I don't touch mergesort for a while, I forget where to add the +1. Is there an easier way to remember this? Thank you.

Comment: BTW "without doing this whole example array of size 10 in my head"...this thing you need to do all the time when working on algorithms, so don't worry. and you should not "remember" , you should understand why its that way.

Comment: @SomeDude Ahh ok, thank you. I was just wondering if others were having the same problem as I did, but I guess I'll just do that.

Comment: First thing is that the way we calculate the size of the array when we have start and end index is `(endIndex - startIndex) + 1`  we add one because the index starts from `0`. 
Now to answer your question  merge sort divides the array into 2 subarrays with indexing `(low, mid)` and `(mid + 1, high)` so to just calculate the size of left array and right array just apply the formulae to find the size of array when we know the index i.e : 
For left: `(mid-low) + 1`) and For right: (high - (mid +1)) + 1` so we can simplify it as `-1 and +1` gets cancelled. i.e: `high -mid -1 + 1 = high - mid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Overflow bug

First, you should never add and then divide indexes. If the array is very large and you are near the end of the array, the `low` and `high` indexes can sum to a negative number if they overflow `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Then, dividing that by two will give a negative value instead of the positive value you were expecting.

Here's [a Google blog post about the issue](https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html). The corrected way in Java is (note that that's `>>>`, not `>>`):

```java
int mid = (high + low) >>> 1;
```

#### Reasoning

With that said, here's the hard way to figure it out followed by the easy way to figure it out.

The issue is how to handle an even or odd `low` value and an even or odd `high` value so that the left and right sides are always fairly balanced in size.

Let's make a table with acceptable `lSize` and `rSize` values that balance properly:

```
┏━━━━┯━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ low ╲ high ┃     4      ┃     5      ┃
┣━━━━━━┷━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃     0      ┃ 2/3 or 3/2 │    3/3     ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━╉────────────┼────────────┨
┃     1      ┃    2/2     │ 2/3 or 3/2 ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

The associated `mid` values are:

```
┏━━━━┯━━━━━━━┳━━━┳━━━┓
┃ low ╲ high ┃ 4 ┃ 5 ┃
┣━━━━━━┷━━━━━╋━━━╇━━━┫
┃     0      ┃ 2 │ 2 ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━╉───┼───┨
┃     1      ┃ 2 │ 3 ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━┷━━━┛
```

So, we know it's going to be something like `mid - low` and `high - mid`, but we might need to adjust it. Do those add up to the total size you're working with?

```
┏━━━━┯━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ low ╲ high ┃           4           ┃           5           ┃
┣━━━━━━┷━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫
┃     0      ┃ (2 - 0) + (4 - 2) = 4 │ (2 - 0) + (5 - 2) = 5 ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━╉───────────────────────┼───────────────────────┨
┃     1      ┃ (2 - 1) + (4 - 2) = 3 │ (3 - 1) + (5 - 3) = 4 ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┷━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
```

So, we're one less than where we need to be, so we need to add one to either `mid - low` or `high - mid`, but which one? Well, we make tables for both and compare to our first table.

What happens if we add the one to `mid - low`?

```
┏━━━━┯━━━━━━━┳━━━━━┳━━━━━┓
┃ low ╲ high ┃  4  ┃  5  ┃
┣━━━━━━┷━━━━━╋━━━━━╇━━━━━┫
┃     0      ┃ 3/2 │ 3/3 ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━╉─────┼─────┨
┃     1      ┃ 2/2 │ 3/2 ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━┷━━━━━┛
```

As you can see, that matches the acceptable options in our very first table. What happens if we add the one to `high - mid`?

```
┏━━━━┯━━━━━━━┳━━━━━┳━━━━━┓
┃ low ╲ high ┃  4  ┃  5  ┃
┣━━━━━━┷━━━━━╋━━━━━╇━━━━━┫
┃     0      ┃ 2/3 │ 2/4 ┃
┣━━━━━━━━━━━━╉─────┼─────┨
┃     1      ┃ 1/3 │ 2/3 ┃
┗━━━━━━━━━━━━┻━━━━━┷━━━━━┛
```

As you can see, that's unbalanced.

So, we have `mid - low + 1` and `high - mid`.

#### Easy way to figure it out

Have it debug print the `lSize` and `rSize` values (`System.err.printf("L:%d R:%d\n", lSize, rSize);`) with the one added to `lSize` and then with the one added to `rSize`. Try with different array sizes and see which balances the left and right sides the best.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example. Say the list has 10 elements. Here are the indices in the list

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Now, the list has to be split in half and each half sorted recursively - 0 1 2 3 4 in one half, 5 6 7 8 9 in the other. So the first half has to stop at 4, and the second half has to start at 5 and end at 9.

If you calculate the half way point `mid = (9 + 0) / 2`, it should be 4.5, but since this is integer maths, it is truncated (not rounded, *truncated*) to 4. So you use `mid` (4) as the end of the first half, and `mid + 1` (5) as the start of the second half.

I hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't what I was asking for. I understand the concept of splitting the array in half, but I am just having trouble understanding the size of the left subarray.

Comment: The size of the left array is half of the original array size, truncated to an integer. Thats what I just explained. The `+1` is only there so the entry at `mid` doesn't get included in both halves.